# FPGA what clock frequency

Tags: fpga, frequency, clock

I have a fpga that is taking in serial data at a bit rate of say 4.8 kbps.

Now I am not sure what clock frequency my fpga should run at to properly handle the data.

Will the clock speed simply need to be at minimum 4800 Hz?

Comment: Might get a better answer over on [electronics.se]

Comment: But just in case you come back and find one/some answer helpful enough, please dont forget about accepting it at some point.

Answer (score 1):

It goes the other way round: you first have to determine how many clock cycles you need to process a **single** input "tick". If one cycle is enough to complete your processing, then 4800 Hz might be fine.

But if you need two cycles, then you would probably go with double speed.

This is a pretty generic answer, but your question is also pretty generic, so this is probably the best you can hope for without enhancing your input.

Answer (score 0):

> Will the clock speed simply need to be at minimum 4800 Hz?

Theoretical: yes, practical: no.

Theoretical.
You can receive a 4800 Hz signal with a 4800Hz clock but only if the clock is the **exact** right frequency. (The 4800 Hz will deviate, no clock is perfect). For that you would need something like a PLL which is in a measurement feedback loop looking at the signal en keeping the clock in step.

Practical.
Much easier is to use e.g. a 1MHz FPGA clock and use over-sampling. Even then you have the same problems as with a dedicated clock: you need to know where the bit boundaries are. Again some sort of clock locking or edge recognition mechanism is required. In fact you have to build the equivalent of a PLL but you can do it all using registers and counters.
When running at 1MHz (which is very slow for an FPGA) you have plenty of clock cycles to process your data.

Both methods depend on the protocol you are using which you did not mention. They are only possible for some type of signals/serial protocols.  For example if signals are low or high for many clock cycles that would cause problems for either method.